# The method was called on null

Tags: firebase, navigation, flutter, analytics, init

I am trying to use firebase analytics to follow the user navigation and pressing on some buttons i made a `_currentScreen()` function which i call init state in the class in which the user navigates to
here is the function

```
Future<Null> _currentScreen() async {
    await widget.analytics.setCurrentScreen(
        screenName: 'second screen view', screenClassOverride: 'SecondScreenView');
  }
```

and i made another function which is _sendAnalytics which i call when the user click on a button; here is the function:

```
 Future<Null> _sendAnalytics() async {
    await widget.analytics
        .logEvent(name: 'launchhhh', parameters: <String, dynamic>{});

  }
```

I have several problems: 
1st- in the initstate in the second screen class it's warning :is method overrides a method annotated as @mustCallSuper in 'State', but does not invoke the overridden method.
2nd- when i run the code and press the button of navigations i have this

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (12744): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'logEvent' was called on null.
E/flutter (12744): Receiver: null
E/flutter (12744): Tried calling: logEvent(name: "launchhhh", parameters: _LinkedHashMap len:0)
E/flutter (12744): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (12744): #1      FirstScreenState._sendAnalytics (file:///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/wedn2/wedn2/lib/h.dart:40:10)
```

3- Also, when i comment the _sendanalytics function

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'setCurrentScreen' was called on null.
E/flutter (15612): Receiver: null
E/flutter (15612): Tried calling: setCurrentScreen(screenClassOverride: "SecondScreenView", screenName: "second screen view")
E/flutter (15612): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (15612): #1      SecondScreenState._currentScreen (file:///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/wedn2/wedn2/lib/h.dart:91:28)
E/flutter (15612): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15612): #2      SecondScreenState.initState (file:///C:/Users/pc/Desktop/wedn2/wedn2/lib/h.dart:88:5)
E/flutter (15612): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3787:58)
E/flutter (15612): #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3653:5)
```

I don't know where is the problem any help? and here is my whole code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics/observer.dart';

import 'dart:async';


 class MyAppf extends StatelessWidget {
  static FirebaseAnalytics analytics = new FirebaseAnalytics();
  static FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
      new FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[observer],
      // home: new WallScreen(analytics: analytics, observer: observer),
      home: new FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
}
class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;
  FirstScreen({this.analytics, this.observer});


  @override
  FirstScreenState createState() => new FirstScreenState();
}
class FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  Future<Null> _sendAnalytics() async {
    await widget.analytics
        .logEvent(name: 'launchhhh', parameters: <String, dynamic>{});

  }

    final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;
  FirstScreenState({this.analytics, this.observer});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),


      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Launch screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
            );
           _sendAnalytics();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;
  SecondScreen({this.analytics, this.observer});



  @override
  SecondScreenState createState() => new SecondScreenState();
}

class SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _currentScreen();
  }
   Future<Null> _currentScreen() async {
    await widget.analytics.setCurrentScreen(
        screenName: 'second screen view', screenClassOverride: 'SecondScreenView');
  }
  Future<Null> _sendAnalyticsback() async {
    await widget.analytics
        .logEvent(name: 'back', parameters: <String, dynamic>{});

  }
  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;
  SecondScreenState({this.analytics, this.observer});  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          _sendAnalyticsback();
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );


  }

}
```

*EDIT* I passed my var analytics to Widgets to be

```
 home:new FirstScreen(analytics: analytics),
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(analytics:analytics)),
```

instead of :

```
home:new FirstScreen(),
Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
```

But still it's the same error calling on null

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your var analytics to your Widgets.

```
new FirstScreen(),
new SecondScreen(),
```

Should be :

```
new FirstScreen(analytics: analytics),
new SecondScreen(analytics: analytics),
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply; i did so but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Do not use static members as they are intended to be accessed through the class itself. A cealner way of what you are trying to do is declare `MyApp` as a `SatetfulWidget` , now you `analytics` and `observer` can be private members of `State` class and use `initState` to initialize them, see the following example:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
   FirebaseAnalytics _analytics;
   FirebaseAnalyticsObserver _observer ;
  @override
    void initState() {
      _analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
      _observer = FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: _analytics);
      super.initState();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container();
  }
}
```

If you want to keep your widget `Stateless` you can initialize your `observer` in the constructor's initializer list, this requires the `analytics` field to be passed a value when `MyApp` is created `MyApp(analytics:FirebaseAnalytics())`:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer;

  MyApp({Key key,@required this.analytics})
      : observer = FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
        super(key: key);



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```